# propel:build schema driver fails

Tags: symfony1, propel, jobeet

I'm doing jobeet day 3 and I copied the schema.yml into the config directory and so I'm trying to create a database schema and I ran:

$sudo php symfony propel:build-schema

> > propel    Running "reverse" phing task
> >     [propel-schema-reverse] There was an error building XML from metadata: could not find driver

Some problems occurred when executing the task
    If the exception message is not clear enough, read the output of the task for more information

At first it appeared that I needed a driver pdo.so, but then I read that pdo is now integrated into php5 which I am using on my Ubuntu (wubi) system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed php -m to display pdo_mysql

Comment: In other words, you need to enable the `php_pdo_mysql` extension in your `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

why doin' with sudo?